# Get duration of Windows Media Player 12 supported movie types in c# web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-media-player

I know it sounds similar to many other questions, but I haven't found anything that applies exactly to my situation.

- This is a c# **Web Application** using MVC.
- I need to, in the controller, get the duration of a file given the filepath (guaranteed to be local to the server)
- The requirement is to support all media types that WMP 12 supports

Given those conditions, none of the solutions I can find out there seem to work.  COM components would require installing WMP to the server(not allowed) or Active X controls wouldn't help on the controller side. Do I have any good options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I never got any answers/good options for this.  We pulled the feature until such time that access to the webserver via installing WMP or using Shell calls will be available.